# Concat string dynamically Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I should concatenate an HTML string (i.e. `"<div>HTML string</div>"`) to compose dinamically a description for [Guider-JS](https://github.com/roydukkey/Guiders-JS).

I tried to do that using **concat** method but doesn't work.

```
var str = "<div><p>first test:</p><ul>";
    for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        str+=("<li class='pointer' onclick=alert('hello')>" + list[i] + "</li>");
    }
    console.log("one " + str);
```

Otherwise, if I use **+=** operator works well.

```
var str = "<div><p>second test:</p><ul>";
    for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        str.concat("<li class='pointer' onclick=alert('hello')>" + list[i] + "</li>");
    }
    console.log("two " + str);
```

I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0coqek0/) for explain better the case.

Sorry for my question, maybe is trivial but i don't understand why this happen

Comment: `an HTML string (i.e. "HTML string")` Best. Clarification. Ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) **returns** the new string with the concatenated values, so you want to assign that result to `str`: `str = str.concat(...`

Note that if you're using `concat`, you don't need `+` anymore:

```
str = str.concat("<li class='pointer' onclick=alert('hello')>", list[i], "</li>");
// -----------------------------------------------------------^^-------^^
```

Comment: Thank you! simply I missed to assign

Answer (score 2):

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0coqek0/1/)

make it

```
str  = str.concat("<li class='pointer' onclick=alert('hello')>" + list[i] + "</li>");
```